# Notation for change-of-coordinate matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, change-of-basis

I'm currently working through David Lay's [Linear Algebra and Its Applications](https://www.amazon.ca/Linear-Algebra-Its-Applications-5th/dp/032198238X) and I'm a bit confused by the notation used for the change-of-coordinate matrix.

If $\mathscr{B}$ and $\mathscr{C}$ are bases of a vector space $V$, then the change-of-coordinate matrix from $\mathscr{B}$ to $\mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{C}$ to $\mathscr{B}$ are denoted by
$P_{\mathscr{C}\leftarrow\mathscr{B}}$ and $P_{\mathscr{B}\leftarrow\mathscr{C}}$ respectively.

What I'm wondering is if there is a reason that the arrow points from right to left as opposed to common limit notation in calculus that is read from left to right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, $P_{\mathscr{C}\leftarrow\mathscr{B}}$ acts on vectors from the left, taking a vector $[v]_{\mathscr{B}}$ and producing a vector $P_{\mathscr{C}\leftarrow\mathscr{B}} [v]_{\mathscr{B}} = [v]_{\mathscr{C}}$, so you can see how $\mathscr{B}$ is being sucked into $P$ to produce $\mathscr{C}$.

Comment: Right on, that makes a ton of sense. Thank you!